# Svelte - on:change handler on input fires only after blur event

Tags: javascript, svelte

I built a custom input field:

```
<div class="field-wrapper">
  <input
    title={passwordError[$language]}
    name="password"
    on:change={e => updatePasswordError(password.length < 8)}
    bind:value={password}
    placeholder="Password"
    type="password" />
  <div style={`opacity: ${passwordError.show ? 1 : 0}`}>
    {passwordError[$language]}
  </div>
</div>
```

The password variable is initiated with null at the top of the file. My problem is that the on:change handler does not fire with every new character, but only with the first one and after I leave the field (so on the on blur event). So what did I do wrong? My goal is that the error message disappears after it has the correct length.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is most probably due fact change event on text input is specified to behave this way ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event ); for instant calls try `input` (Svelte `on:input`) or keyup events as suggested.

Comment: Ahh, you are right. I forgot that the native implementation works this way. I have a React background, so I am used to another way ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="field-wrapper">
  <input
    title={passwordError[$language]}
    name="password"
    on:keyup={e => updatePasswordError(password.length < 8)}
    bind:value={password}
    placeholder="Password"
    type="password" />
  <div style={`opacity: ${passwordError.show ? 1 : 0}`}>
    {passwordError[$language]}
  </div>
</div>
```

the input here should call the function every time you press any key inside this input

Comment: `input` event would also be triggered on pasting clipboard value with mouse only. `keyup` will not.

Comment: the lack of trigger for pasting with mouse is easily fixed by handling `blur`: `on:blur={e => updatePasswordError(password.length < 8)}` in addition to `keyup`

Answer (score 2):

You should use [reactive statements](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-statements) in case you want to call a function on value change.

```
<script>
$:updatePasswordError(password.length < 8)
</script>
```